# Как перехватить действие GestureOverlayView

Tags: android, gestures

Долго изучал документацию `GestureOverlayView`, но так и не нашел то, что мне надо.

Подскажите, как поймать тот моммент, когда `GestureOverlayView` понимает, что символ не расспознан. То есть, когда жесты рисуешь, в начале цвет Светло - желтый, а если есть совпадение, то он становиться желтым. Так вот, мне надо поймать, когда он светло - желтый.

То есть, рисуешь символ - жест рисуется светло - желтым цветом и пропадает. В этот момент мне надо его поймать. Как сделать это, скажите пожалуйста?

Может я непонятно объяснил, могу еще подробнее, если что то не понятно.

Под "БЕЛО - ЖЕЛТЫМ" я имею ввиду

[image: [БЕЛО - ЖЕЛТЫЙ]()]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете организовать какую-то логику в методе обратного вызова `onGesturePerfomed()` интерфейса  [`OnGesturePerformedListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener.html), который занимается тем, что распознает начерченный жест. После того, как жест введен, мы попадаем сюда для его распознавания.

Если этого недостаточно, то, видимо, вам нужно ловить через [`МotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) состояние [`ACTION_UP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP) (жест закончен) в методе обратного вызова `onGesture()` интерфейса [`OnGestereListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener.html#onGestureCancelled(android.gesture.GestureOverlayView,%20android.view.MotionEvent)).

Comment: Я пробовал, когда жест еще не желтый, а бело желтый. тоесть под бело желтым я имею ввиду вот это 
"android:uncertainGestureColor", и когда пропадает бело желтый жест, то в слушателе onGesturePerfomed(), ничего не происходит.    onGesturePerfomed работает только тогда когда жест становиться желтым. Можете даже проверить.     Я хочу найти метод который запускается до запуска onGesturePerfomed. [ВОТ ПРИМЕР БЕЛО - ЖЕЛТЫЙ](http://algebra.sci.csueastbay.edu/~grewe/CS4521/Mat/Android/Gestures/Android_Gestures2.jpg)

Comment: @ddyadyafedya Ну а ACTION_UP в onGesture() что? По идее это событие самое первое по окончании жеста

Comment: if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) не работает в onGestre.

А вообщем ACTION_UP это не (жест закончен, а палец отпушен.). Но вы не забывайте что может быть установлен таймер setFadeOffset или setDurationOffset. Тогда ACTION_UP сработает после того как палец отпущен. А обработка все равно будет происходить. Думаю это не вариант. Блин почему документация андроида всегда не полная блин.

Comment: А как вообще выключить бело желтую линию (не поменять цвет а выключить), чтобы как только ты дотронулся до экрана он уже был как распознанный, тоесть желтый?

Comment: Ответье кто нибудь

Comment: @ddyadyafedya Если вам не нравится, что эта "бело-желтая" линия появляется и вы хотите от нее избавиться - установите `android:uncertainGestureColor="#00000000",` - прозрачный цвет для этой линии.